# Form Submission using Enter Key

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get the Enter key to submit this form but it is refreshing the page instead. Any Solutions?

```
<form onSubmit={() => handleSubmit()}>
          <label for="text">Enter Task</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" value = {input} onInput = {(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}></input>
          <button type = "submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

This is my handleSubmit() function:

```
const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    //function logic
```

I have tried using the preventDefault() function but that does not seem to work

Comment: Instead of `onSubmit` use `onClick`.

Comment: I remember doing this by adding an eventListener to the holding div for when the enter key is pressed, then run the submit function on capture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue you have here is that `e.preventDefault()` is not working as expected because `e` is not defined. You need to pass params to handleSubmit() doing one of the following

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}></form>

<form onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}></form>
```